# Windows Stand Alone Application Stops Auto Refresh when moved into background

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a windows standalone application which I auto refresh based on a particular user defined interval. Everything is fine, only if the application is in background and I have opened something else in the desktop, the application stops the auto refresh.

I am using a time for the refresh. Here is the code.

The Global.DateTime value will get the previous refreshed value.

```c#
Global.DateTime = Global.DateTime; 
double Minutes = Convert.ToDouble(Global.dictionary["WebserviceIntervalMins"].ToString()); DateTime refreshDate = Global.DateTime.AddMinutes(Minutes); 
lblRefresh.Text = refreshDate.ToString();

public void InitTimer()
{
    int interv =  Convert.ToInt32(Global.dictionary["WebserviceIntervalMins"].ToString()) * 60000; // Get the interval time from config file and convert minutes into milliseconds
    timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = interv; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "auto refresh" ? Are you using a Timer ? Please show some code.

Comment: @mrlucmorin Yes I am using a time for the refresh. Here is the code. The Global.DateTime value will get the previous refreshed value.
Global.DateTime = Global.DateTime;
double Minutes = Convert.ToDouble(Global.dictionary["WebserviceIntervalMins"].ToString());
DateTime refreshDate = Global.DateTime.AddMinutes(Minutes);
lblRefresh.Text = refreshDate.ToString();

Comment: Please update your original question with any relevant code. Do not use comments for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is of very little help here. When is this code called ? You'll need to provide more details if you expect others to help.

Comment: @mrlucmorin updated the initTimer code as well.  does this help?

Answer (score -1):

Can you use something like that?

```
    bool isRunning = true;
    Thread th = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        while(isRunning)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                //do refresh
            });
            int Minutes = Convert.ToInt(Global.dictionary["WebserviceIntervalMins"].ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(Minutes * 60000);
        }
   });
   th.IsBackground = true;
   th.Start();
```

Comment: This is just bad advice, infinite while loops with `Thread.Sleep` is almost never the correct answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain who said infinite? Common sense dictates that isRunning should be changed to false when it's required - before form close for example.

Comment: Its infinite enough. There is no reason to have a sleeping thread to do this. This is exactly what timers where created to do.

Comment: Can you please explain why you call this loop infinite since exit condition is clearly defined - !isRunnung?